# Where can i get this file jquery.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for making a website and i am stuck with this jquery file named jquery.min.js which is not inside the bootstrap package which we download from it's official site. It's been mentioned on the official bootstrap website that the version of jquery.min.js used here is 1.9.0 ie jquery - 1.9.0 but i am not able to link myself to the respective file, all i could get closer to is jquery-ui.min.js.
I am just a jquery beginner and so i dont even know that are they different or same. If they are different then Where can i find the exact jquery - 1.9.0 version jquery.min.js file?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the jQuery versions CDN from [here](https://code.jquery.com/).
And add this to your HTML inside `<script>` tags.